# Vectorizing NumPy covariance for 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization, covariance

I have a 3D numpy array of shape `(t, n1, n2)`:

```
x = np.random.rand(10, 2, 4)
```

I need to calculate another 3D array `y` which is of shape `(t, n1, n1)` such that:

```
y[0] = np.cov(x[0,:,:])
```

...and so on for all slices along the first axis.

So, a loopy implementation would be:

```
y = np.zeros((10,2,2))
for i in np.arange(x.shape[0]):
    y[i] = np.cov(x[i, :, :])
```

Is there any way to vectorize this so I can calculate all covariance matrices in one go? I tried doing:

```
x1 = x.swapaxes(1, 2)
y = np.dot(x, x1)
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hacked into [`numpy.cov source code`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L2287) and tried using the default parameters. As it turns out, `np.cov(x[i,:,:])` would be simply :

```
N = x.shape[2]
m = x[i,:,:]
m -= np.sum(m, axis=1, keepdims=True) / N
cov = np.dot(m, m.T)  /(N - 1)
```

So, the task was to vectorize this loop that would iterate through `i` and process all of the data from `x` in one go. For the same, we could use `broadcasting` at the third step. For the final step, we are performing `sum-reduction` there along all slices in first axis. This could be efficiently implemented in a vectorized manner with `np.einsum`. Thus, the final implementation came to this -

```
N = x.shape[2]
m1 = x - x.sum(2,keepdims=1)/N
y_out = np.einsum('ijk,ilk->ijl',m1,m1) /(N - 1)
```

**Runtime test**

```
In [155]: def original_app(x):
     ...:     n = x.shape[0]
     ...:     y = np.zeros((n,2,2))
     ...:     for i in np.arange(x.shape[0]):
     ...:         y[i]=np.cov(x[i,:,:])
     ...:     return y
     ...: 
     ...: def proposed_app(x):
     ...:     N = x.shape[2]
     ...:     m1 = x - x.sum(2,keepdims=1)/N
     ...:     out = np.einsum('ijk,ilk->ijl',m1,m1)  / (N - 1)
     ...:     return out
     ...: 

In [156]: # Setup inputs
     ...: n = 10000
     ...: x = np.random.rand(n,2,4)
     ...: 

In [157]: np.allclose(original_app(x),proposed_app(x))
Out[157]: True  # Results verified

In [158]: %timeit original_app(x)
1 loops, best of 3: 610 ms per loop

In [159]: %timeit proposed_app(x)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.32 ms per loop
```

Huge speedup there!

Comment: Thanks Divakar, looking into it in detail now to understand einsum.

Comment: I just changed N/(N**2-N) to 1/(N-1) in your code to align with standard formula and ease of understanding

Comment: @Divakar, could you please explain in more detail this step: `m1 = x - x.sum(2,keepdims=1)/N`? Changing the `.sum` axis, does not seem to affect the final answer...

Comment: Another  way, not as fast as the einsum way is: ```out = (m1 @ m1.transpose(0,2,1)) / (N - 1)``` which follows from the definition of the [sample covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Estimation).